# Store current time and check it is in range or not in Luxon js

Tags: javascript, luxon

I am using Luxon and passing different timezones via html code. I want to store current time in variable and to check time is in range or not. I have three times. One for opening office time, lunch time and last closing time.

For instance
Opening time : 09:15 to 12:59 pm
Lunch Time :  01:00 Pm to 02:00 Pm
Closing time : 02:01 pm to 4:30 pm

When time fall in this ranges, status get automatically change (Open, Lunch, Close)

With hour only not helping, i need whole time in current date.

Kindly help me. Any type of guidance would be appreciated.

```
const locations = document.querySelectorAll("section.Timezone div")

const updateTimes = function () {
  locations.forEach(location => {
    const output = location.querySelector("output")
    const timezone = location.getAttribute("Country_Timezone")
    const now = luxon.DateTime.now().setZone(timezone)

    output.innerHTML = now.toFormat("HH:mm:ss")

    const hour = parseInt(now.toFormat("H"))
    if(hour >=9 && hour <18)
    {
      location.classList.add("open")
    }
  })
}

updateTimes() 

setInterval(function () {
  updateTimes()
}, 1000)`
```

Comment: No response from anyone

Comment: You can use `now.hour` instead of formatting and then parsing the string. Outside of that, I'm not really sure what your question is?